# Grouping javadoc methods

Tags: java, javadoc

I'd like to group the methods in the javadoc for my class.
For example:

```
Admin methods:
   blah1
   blah2
Accessor methods:
   foo1
   foo2
```

Do you know of any way I can achieve this in javadoc?
Are there any doclets available for doing this?

Thanks,
Calum

Comment: That would be nice. I hate the alphabetical grouping being the only option.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to create a [custom doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#doclets) to generate the HTML according to your specific needs..

Comment: Link is broken. Maybe: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html